# Error signing an ios app with trigger.io

Tags: trigger.io, provisioning-profile

I get the following error when trying to run an ios app with trigger.io (on windows)

```
[ERROR] Failed when running C:\Users\\*\.lib\win-ios-install.exe: Installing c:\users\\*\appdata\local\temp\tmpx8ahhx to: 83d9adbf9f921920918cec34e93cbacddd1f17a3
Install - CreatingStagingDirectory (5%)
Install - ExtractingPackage (15%)
Install - InspectingPackage (20%)
Install - TakingInstallLock (20%)
Install - PreflightingApplication (30%)
Install - InstallingEmbeddedProfile (30%)
Install - VerifyingApplication (40%)
Install - Error occured: ApplicationVerificationFailed
```

I have followed the instrutions from [ios setup](https://trigger.io/docs/current/tools/ios-windows.html#setting-up-forge-to-run-ios-apps) to the t. Any idea what could be the issue?

Comment: Is there a verbose mode? Need more info.